# simpledateformat.format take a long time (cpu time) how to resolve?

Tags: android, performance, simpledateformat

I am using the my own function:

```
    public static String getFormatedDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    return   sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

and it's give me the exat result I want, but when I run traceView to improve performance I find tht this function takes 12.238ms, and when I check the function child, to see where is the problem, I foun:

```
simpledateformat<init>  |  6.47ms
simpledateformat.format |  5.015ms
```

1. I am not good in understanding trace results, but it is clear that here is
   the problem.
2. these are system functions (I.e not my function so no way to improve them)

what may I do in this case, are my understanding of trace right? what is the alternatives of this expensive function??

**BTW: where may I find good recource od deep understanding the trace?**

take a kook at the screenshoot:
[image: screencapure]

Comment: The function might be expensive on Dalvik, but performs better on ART. IMHO there's possibly no better alternative.

Comment: i don't think these are actual ms. If you want to improve it, you can take the init of SDF out of the function, since it is always the same. You also can go deeper in the analysis by clicking on each children to see what takes them so much time.

Comment: thank you   ** frederick nyawaya** @njzk2 : yes it reduce the time from 12 to 4 , but it still long time :) Cuz now no init in my fubction, but I need to improve sampledateFromate.format() it takes 4.xx ms

Comment: This is a formatting function. Unless you are formatting huge amounts of data in a very short time, this should not have a significant impact on your performances.